# metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved when namespace specified

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I have a Class2 and a Class1 in a project shared between service and client.

```
<DataContract(Name:="Class1", Namespace:="http://www.example.com/my/app")> _
Public Class Class1
    <DataMember> _
    Public Property Test
End Class

<DataContract(Name:="Class2{0}", Namespace:="http://www.example.com/my/app")>    
Public Class Class2(Of ReturnType)
    <DataMember> _
    Public Property Test As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Items() As ReturnType()
End Class
```

This is my service interface:

```
<ServiceContract(Name:="Service")> _
Public Interface IService

    <OperationContract()> _
    Function GetStuff() As Class2(Of Class1)

End Interface
```

In my service project I also have a Class1 which inherits from the shared class:

```
<DataContract(Namespace:="http://www.example.com/my/app")>
Public Class Class1
    Inherits [Shared].Entities.Class1

End Class
```

My service config:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <configuration>

        <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
  <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true"/>
</diagnostics>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
<bindings/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServ" name="WcfService1.Service">
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService1.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/service/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServ">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

When I try to Add Service Reference in my client project, I get the error:

The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/service/mex'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost/service/mex'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

If I remove the Namespace from the DataContract attribute on Class1 in the service project I am then able to generate the service reference.  But I have had to add this namespace and removing it will break other things.  How can I generate my service reference whilst leaving the namespace intact?

This also works if I change the namespace to net.tcp instead of http in both the shared and service projects however this isn't a good solution for me as I do not want to have to rebuild existing clients.

Answer (score 0):

There are few details missing in your config.

**netTcpBinding doesnt have any address endpoint**

**The baseaddress doesnt have any port specified.**
If you dont use any port 80 will be used by default only for http.Its always better to overcome this default for http.Incase for nettcp schema you have to explicitly define the port.

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServ" name="WcfService1.Service">
    <endpoint address=""  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService1.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/service/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Now you can add service reference through this address net.tcp://localhost:8080/service/

Comment: Thanks but specifying the port doesn't make any difference to the error.  Besides, this app has been working without the port on net tcp for years and adding the service reference works fine without the namespace.